# What does "buzzard's uncle' mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I came across the phrase, "Well, I'm a buzzard's uncle!" in a paragraph of Holling C. Holling's book, "Tree in the trail". The person who said that was watching something that he did not expect to happen.

Is the phrase "I'm a buzzard's uncle" used to express surprise?

Comment: Probably it was “I’ll be” not “I’m a”??

Comment: I've seen both "I'll be a..." and "I'm a..."; the latter seems to be based on the reasoning "If that happens then I'm a buzzard's uncle. It has happened. Therefore I am a buzzard's uncle." I can't find anything about the origin though it seems to be rural American, and Google books goes back to 1958.

Answer (score 7):

OP's ***buzzard*** version derives from...

> [**I'll be a monkey's uncle!**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey%27s_uncle)
> used as an expression of surprise

...where my guess is it's a "euphemistic" variant. The expression originated about a century ago in the US, against a backdrop of Christian creationists and Darwinian evolutionists arguing about whether humans were descended from "monkeys" (popular parlance for earlier, more primitive hominids).

In the contexts of both that earlier evolution / creationism debate, and today's "anti-racist" culture, "monkey" is a potentially charged word, so OP's variant is perfectly understandable. But there's [only a single instance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I%27ll%20be%20a%20buzzard%27s%20uncle%22) in Google Books, so it obviously doesn't have much traction.

---

The basic construction relies on the idea that both speaker and audience find the postulated scenario implausible *and* "ridiculous / risible". Compare with similar *That's ludicrous!* expressions such as *Well, knock me down with a feather!*

---

Note that these expressions of *surprise* aren't quite the same as, for example,...

> *If that's true then I'm the king of China<sup>1</sup>!*
> (stylised / emphatic phrasing for ***I don't believe that**!*)

...which is generally used to express ***literal disbelief*** rather than extreme surprise. I do sometimes see the "monkey's uncle" version used to convey disbelief, but imho that's a misuse. Not least because surely by now almost everyone accepts that we *are* in fact "genetically related" to monkeys (and lettuce, stereotypically! :) - which maybe wasn't the case when the expression was first coined.

---

<sup>1</sup> Or some other obviously untrue claim, such as *...I'm a Dutchman!*

Comment: The sound of *a buzzard's uncle* might bring to mind *a bastard's uncle*, which is a bit of a scandal in its own right. FYI: when "country folk" in America say *buzzard*, they **do not** mean the *Buteo* hawks (their genus is the Latin for "buzzard") as ornithologists and Brits do when they use that word!! They instead only ever mean one of the New World vultures (probably the turkey vulture *Cathartes aura*), which unlike the vultures of the Old World are actually completely unrelated to hawks. I’m afraid the coiners of *a monkey’s uncle* have never been very sharp about biology—or Latin. :)

Comment: Perhaps. But Google Books has just one instance for each of ***buzzard's*** and ***bastard's***, so I kinda doubt that. Interestingly, there are a good few dozen instances of [*If {thing I don't believe} is true **then I'm a Dutchman's uncle**!*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+dutchman%27s+uncle%22) in Google Books. But all the ones I looked at were for the "disbelief" sense, not "astonished".

Comment: Considering _Tree in the Trail_ was written in 1942, it is doubtful the author's use of "buzzard" in place of "monkey" had anything to do with anti-racist sentiment. More likely he just felt like taking a common idiom and put his own spin on it.

Comment: My guess is the monkey -> buzzard switch is mostly to give the expression a "Wild West" feel.

Comment: The "Dutchman's uncle" variant is of course problematic as you'd have to know certain facts about the speaker.  If you heard the phrase from an older gentleman in the Netherlands, for example, it might have a completely different meaning.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: That's the situation in [the very first result](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Good_Hope/4q9GBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22a+dutchman%27s+uncle%22&pg=PA252&printsec=frontcover) from the link in my comment! *If that's being beaten then I'm a Dutchman's uncle!' Tau looked at him for a moment then burst out laughing. 'You ARE a bloody Dutchman's Uncle – look at **your nephew**, Neelsie. I believe his  full sobriquet is Corneels JohannesWillemJocobus De Jager. He **couldn't be much more Dutch if you put him in clogs and gave him a clay pipe.'** :)*